# Enable ssl for spring boot application works on windows but fails on centos 7

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

The below code takes config settings from the application yml to configure ssl :

```
try {
            final String keyStorePassword = Files.toString(Paths.get(appSslConfig.getKeystorePasswordPath()).toFile(), Charsets.UTF_8);
            final String keyPassword = Files.toString(Paths.get(appSslConfig.getKeyPasswordPath()).toFile(), Charsets.UTF_8);

            factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
                Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
                protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
                connector.setScheme(CONNECTOR_SCHEME);
                connector.setSecure(true);
                protocol.setKeystoreType(appSslConfig.getKeystoreType());
                protocol.setKeystoreFile(appSslConfig.getKeystorePath());
                protocol.setKeystorePass(keyStorePassword);
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(keyPassword)) {
                    protocol.setKeyPass(keyPassword);
                }
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(appSslConfig.getKeystoreAlias())) {
                    protocol.setKeyAlias(appSslConfig.getKeystoreAlias());
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occured while loading keyStore.", exception);
            throw exception;
        }
```

The custom properties in the application.yml look like this :

```
app:
  response-delay: 10000
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    keystore-type: JKS
    keystore-path: C:\Users\me\Downloads\mock\src\main\resources\keystore.jks
    keystore-password-path: C:\Users\me\Downloads\mock\src\main\resources\password
    key-password-path: C:\Users\me\Downloads\mock\src\main\resources\password
    keystore-alias:
```

I create the keystore using the following command :

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.jks -validity 3650
```

The password I put it in the "password" file against keystore-password-path

This works fine on windows.

However as I deploy it on centos 7 VM I get the following error :

```
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-7001]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:250) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:193) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at com.my.mock.AppSslConfig.main(AppSslConfig.java:13) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [mock-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [mock-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [mock-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [mock-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1021) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:116) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:204) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:204) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        ... 21 more
```

I triple checked and the password in the file is correct. The file has read permissions and the paths are correct.

I cant figure out what goes wrong when I deploy the same code on VM. Can anyone please help?

Comment: How did you 'triple check'? With a hex or octal dump? With an editor -- which and with what settings? With cat, more, less, or similar -- which and with what options? Did you create a new file in the VM or copy the one from Windows?

Comment: Jeez I dont even know what an hex or octal dump is will check thanks. And triple check means I opened it thrice and verified the password :-p..I created the file manually using-> touch file_name-> vi file_name->typed in the password->wq so no windows. I actually could solve the problem by printf %s "$(< filename)" > temp_pwd.

Comment: Editing with vi (or ed, or most other Unix text utilities) **includes a newline** at the end of the/each line. That is not visible on the screen, but it changes the contents of the file as read by your code and causes the problem. Reading a file (or command) with `$(...)` removes the trailing newline(s). Using `FileReader` (or `FileInputStream` + `InputStreamReader`) and `BufferedReader.readLine` or now popular `Scanner.nextLine` would also remove the newline, and arguably be more convenient.

Comment: ok great thanks for the information!